# Best HTML Canvas JavaScript Library / Wrapper

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm looking for a JavaScript Library or Wrapper for HTML Canvas element that provides following high level features for RAD.

1. Dragging drawing
2. Resizing drawing
3. Creating drawing mesh (drawing with circle, rectangle, lines, paths, image altogether)
4. Can draw any Photoshop drawing on Canvas (I'm going to draw things with Photoshop first and then to Canvas)

I think that would do the job. Look forward to best library ever written!

**UPDATED**

If anyhow ExtJS can do that, that would be wonderful! I am not much into ExtJS drawing engine so not sure if it can do that.

Comment: Take a look at this comparison table —  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Aqj_mVmuz3Y8dHNhUVFDYlRaaXlyX0xYSTVnalV5ZlE#gid=0

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [KineticJS](http://kineticjs.com/).
It removes all the hassles out of canvas programming.

Comment: The thing is that KineticJS looks at canvas in a most intuitive way and provides a wonderful API. You want event handling, draggability, layers (which is a pain in html5 canvas otherwise). All that KineticJS does pretty good. If you are okay with jsut vector graphics, in that case you should look at [raphaeljs](http://raphaeljs.com)

Comment: So KineticJS draws things on a single Canvas? I also want to save things as Image.

Comment: KineticJS allows saving the altered image as a jpg. No problem.